# android calling a MainActivity function from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to android and I'm trying to get a hang of creating and using Fragments.

I have a fragment that shows a simple list of multiple dates to choose from and implements an onClickListener. The idea is once a user chooses a date, the fragments sends the date back to the MainActivity which then runs a query in database and sends the database response to another fragment.

I'm stuck on the point of sending the date back to MainActivity, elegantly. I can't find much info. I found this:

```
 Activity activity = getActivity();
 if(activity instanceof MyActivity){
      MyActivity myactivity = (MyActivity) activity;
      myactivity.myMethod();
}
```

I'm very new to this but this seems hacky to me. Is this the right way or is there another way?

Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the interface based approach because is very clean. You can declare a nested interface in your `Fragment` or an external one:

```
interface OnMyStuffListener {
    void myMethod();
}
```

Make the `Activity` to implement that interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMyStuffListener {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        // Do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

The `Fragment` will be attached to the `Activity` so you can check the instance of the `Context` and cast it to the `Activity`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private OnMyStuffListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnMyStuffListener) {
            mListener = (OnMyStuffListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The context " + context.getClass().getName() +
                    "must implement " + OnMyStuffListener.class.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        // Release it avoiding memory leak.
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YES this is absolutely right. You can use this, if you are not sure that your `Fragment` is attached to `Activity`

You can also achieve this by using `Interface`,  using an `EventBus` like `LocalBroadcastManager`, or starting a new `Activity` with an `Intent` and some form of `flag` passed into its `extras` Bundle or something else.

**Here is an example about using Interface:**

**1.** Add function sendDataToActivity() into the interface (`EventListener`).

```
//EventListener.java

public interface EventListener {

    public void sendDataToActivity(String data);
}
```

**2.** Implement this functions in your `MainActivity`.

```
// MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EventListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToActivity(String data) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "sendDataToActivity: " + data);
    }
}
```

**3.** Create the listener in `MyFragment` and `attach` it to the `Activity`.

**4.** Finally, call function using `listener.sendDataToActivity("Hello World!")`.

```
// MyFragment.java 

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private EventListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity instanceof EventListener) {
            listener = (EventListener)activity;
        } else {
            // Throw an error!
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        // Send data
        listener.sendDataToActivity("Hello World!");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        listener = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~